# i am making a bot which is called dum memer in java

Tags: java

> so here i wanna say that in the code every thing is working fine,
> except the random no. generator. its basically a dank memer" discord
> bot ripoff. so im showing the code, in the rand_int variable ive set it to generate random nos.
> but still it doesnt work pls check the code i wanna generate the rand_int throughout the program

```
import java.util.*;
public class dumMemerFromScratch
{
 public static void main()
 {
   System.out.println("sup nerds,im dum memer");
   System.out.println("im not gunna write everything here so just type <plij help>");
   int bal = 0;
   int min = 0;
   int max = 11;
   int maxBEG = 3500;
   int minBEG = 500;
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   int rand_int = (int)Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
   // i want to keep this rand_int keep generating integers even when the program is running 
   //i know i can place this in a loop but it doesnt work
   int i = 1;
   while (i == 1)
   {
     String cmd = sc.next();
     if (cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("plij_help"))
       {
           System.out.println("follow these: ");
           System.out.println("(P.S. you can also write <plij help |command|> for more info on the command!");
           System.out.println("<plij beg> to beg for some coins lol");
           System.out.println("<plij scout> OR <plij search> to search a specific place n get a chance to get some coins n some times even items!!");
           System.out.println("<plij crime> to commit a crime n get a chance to get some coins");
           System.out.println("<plij hunt> to hunt for animals in the forest(you need a hunting rifle for this)");
           System.out.println("<plij fish> to fish for fishes in the lake(you need a fishing pole for this");
           System.out.println("<plij postmeme> OR <plij pm> to post a meme(you need a laptop for this");
       }
     else if (cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("plij_beg"))
       {
        
           while (i == 1)
           {
           switch(rand_int)
           {
               case 1 :
               {
                   System.out.println("Bo Burnham: ");
                   System.out.println("\"ew go away\"");
               }
               case 2 :
               {
                   int randBEG_int = (int)Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxBEG-minBEG+1)+minBEG);
                   System.out.println("Selena Gomez: ");
                   System.out.println("\"Oh you poor little beggar, take " + randBEG_int + " \"");
                   bal = bal + randBEG_int ;
               }
               case 3 :
               {
                   int randBEG1_int = (int)Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxBEG-minBEG+1)+minBEG);
                   System.out.println("Rick Astley: ");
                   System.out.println("\" Here, take " + randBEG1_int + " \"");
                   bal = bal + randBEG1_int ;
               }
               case 4 :
               {
                   System.out.println("Justin Beiber: ");
                   System.out.println("oh i wouldnt pay for your gambling addiction");
               }
               case 5 :
               {
                   int randBEG2_int = (int)Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxBEG-minBEG+1)+minBEG);
                   System.out.println("Tom Cruise: ");
                   System.out.println("\"oh u jobless person, take " + randBEG2_int + "\"");
                   bal = bal + randBEG2_int ; 
               }
               case 6 :
               {
                   System.out.println("Theresa May: ");
                   System.out.println("\"Honestly why are you even begging, get a job\"");
               }
           }
        }
        }
     else if (cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("quit"))
       {
           System.out.println("Aight then no fun");
           break;
       }
     else 
       {
           System.out.println("sorry i dont understand that, type <plij help> for more info");
       }
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not the way to generate random numbers. Standard library provides quite a few ways to do what you're trying to achieve.

**Random Class**

```
import java.util.Random;
 
public class generateRandom {
 
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        // create instance of Random class
        Random rand = new Random();
 
        // Generate random integers in range 0 to 999
        int rand_int1 = rand.nextInt(1000);
 
        // Print random integers
        System.out.println("Random Integers: " + rand_int1);
    }
}
```

**SecureRandom Class**

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
 
public class generateRandom {
 
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        // create instance of SecureRandom class
        SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();
 
        // Generate random integers in range 0 to 999
        int rand_int1 = rand.nextInt(1000);
 
        // Print random integers
        System.out.println("Random Integers: " + rand_int1);
    }
}
```

I'd recommend the latter approach since it provides a cryptographically strong random number generator.

**Reference:**
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html